# adding map control to xamarin project breaks it

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin (came from C# and WPF)

I build a Xamarin form application using the template provided (VS created it for me)

I add Xamarin.Forms.Map from the nuget and added it to a page like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
              xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="XamarinTest.Views.MapPage"
             Title="Map"
             >
    <!--Title="{Binding Title}"-->



    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <!--<ToolbarItem Text="Add" Clicked="AddItem_Clicked" />-->
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <StackLayout Spacing="10">
         <maps:Map x:Name="map" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Now the application doesn't work and I am getting an error which says the code can not be debugged using this debugger. (I am using UWP platform)

When I commented out the map, it would work and there is no problem.

I tested it on Android and I am getting similar errors when reference to map exist.

What is the problem and how I can fix it?

Comment: did you read the docs?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/setup

Comment: Could you share a test project, I could not reproduce your issue,i add the map,and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comments, I found that I need to initialize the map in each implementation.

For example UWP we should have this line in MainPage.xaml.cs

```
Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init("INSERT_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN_HERE");
```

This is a good document on how to initialise map on different platforms:

[Xamarin.Forms Map Initialization and Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/setup)